# Unable to send messages back to client

Tags: python, sockets, terminal, serversocket

I am trying to get a client to communicate with two separate servers (Kerberos implementation). I am trying to get both servers to communicate with the client and each other. So far, I am only able to send a message to both server1 and server2. However, when I try to send the messages from the server back to the client,

I get this warning:
`A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied`

This is the code I have/tried:

**client.py**

```
import sys
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

SERVER_IP   = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 5544
PORT2 = 6644
SIZE = 1024
IDc = "CIS3319USERID"
IDv = "CIS3319SERVERID" 
IDtgs = "CIS3319TGSID"
print ("\t====\tClient\t====")

connection = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
#while true get message from user and send it to servers
while True:
        msg = input("Enter message to send: ")
        connection.sendto(msg.encode(),(SERVER_IP,PORT))
        connection.sendto(msg.encode(),(SERVER_IP,PORT2))
        (data,addr) = connection.recvfrom(SIZE)
        print(data.decode())
connection.close()
sys.exit()
```

**server.py**

```
    from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import sys
import time
SERVER_IP   = '127.0.0.1'
PORT_NUMBER = 5544
PORT2 = 6644
SIZE = 1024
IDc = "CIS3319USERID"
IDv = "CIS3319SERVERID" 
IDtgs = "CIS3319TGSID"
hostName = gethostbyname( '0.0.0.0' )

#create a connection
connection = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
connection.bind( (hostName, PORT_NUMBER) )

print ("\t====\tServer-1\t====")
print ("Server1 listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT_NUMBER))

#while true check for incoming messages and print them
while True:
        msg = input("Enter message to send: ")
        connection.sendto(msg.encode(),(SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))
        connection.sendto(msg.encode(),(SERVER_IP,PORT2))
        (data,addr) = connection.recvfrom(SIZE)
        print (data.decode()+ " sent at "+str(time.time())+" Epoch time")
#close connection
connection.close()
sys.exit()
```

**server2.py**

```
from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import sys
PORT = 6644
SIZE = 1024
import time
IDc = "CIS3319USERID"
IDv = "CIS3319SERVERID" 
IDtgs = "CIS3319TGSID"
hostName = gethostbyname( '0.0.0.0' )

#create a connection
connection = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
connection.bind( (hostName, PORT) )

print ("\t====\tServer-2\t====")
print ("Server2 listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT))
#while true check for incoming messages and print them
while True:
        (data,addr) = connection.recvfrom(SIZE)
        print (data.decode()+ " sent at "+str(time.time())+" Epoch time")
#close connection
connection.close()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: At `server.py` your first `send` isn't meant to also be `sendto`? Your socket isn't connected anywhere, thats why the error. Why do you need 2 identical servers?

Comment: @nagyl Thanks for the response. I was able to get the two servers to communicated. However I can still only send one message from the client and now when I try to send a message from the server, it only gets sent to server2.py not the client. Also I have to create 2 separate servers for my assignment, but right now I am just trying to get the server2.py to keep track of the messages being sent between server.py and client.py

Comment: You might want to create a new thread after each connection in server.py, that requires to `accept` connection from the client. Note that you must not `input` first, since that terminates the program while no input is sent. Client.py should connect (using `socket.connect()`) to server.py, they communicate with `send`, and each message should also be sent with `sendto` to `server2`, which can just save all incoming messages. Note that to be able to use send, first you must connect the client socket to the server socket. Example: https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html